# How to edit the item name in Edit Control Block(ECB) using javascript in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

[Click for Image ECB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq2SX.jpg)

I want to edit the item name(Edit Item) to custom name(any) in Edit control block(ECB) of list using JavaScript or jquery in SharePoint. Please advice me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using CSS .

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div[id$="EditItem"] span 
    {
        display: none;
    }

         div[id$="EditItem"]:before 
    {
         content: "Modify this Item";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JavaScript client model to get get the userCustomActions where you can then add, set location and update.

This is explained here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/76082278-9505-4909-b004-a75bc5d1a0e8/create-custom-edit-control-block-using-javascript?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: any luck? did you get it?

Comment: I done that using CSS and heres the code 
div[id$="EditItem"] span {
  display: none;
}
 
div[id$="EditItem"]:before {
  content: "Modify this Item";
}